# lambda instantiation in constructor

Tags: c++, lambda, constructor

I have such a constructor:

```
ConcurrentHashMap(int expected_size, int expected_threads_count, const Hash& hasher = Hash())
    {
      this->my_hash_ = hasher;
      if (expected_size != kUndefinedSize)
         table.reserve(expected_size);
    }
```

When I pass a lambda function for the `hasher` argument:

```
auto lambda = [](const std::pair<int, int>& x) {
    return pair_hash(x);
};
```

I get the errors:

```
: In instantiation of ‘ConcurrentHashMap<K, V, Hash>::ConcurrentHashMap(int, int, const Hash&) [with K = std::pair<int, int>; V = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Hash = Correctness_Constructors_Test::TestBody()::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&)>]’:
   required from here
```

And:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘Correctness_Constructors_Test::TestBody()::<lambda(const std::pair<int, int>&)>::<lambda>()’
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: What does `Hash` look like?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Lambdas are not default constructible and you're trying to default construct one somewhere (probably in the default argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is you default construct `my_hash_` in your constructor member initialization list (because you do not provide one) and then you assign to it in the constructor body.  Since `my_hash_` is a lambda it is not default constructable as lambdas are not default constructable.  You need to initialize `my_hash_` in the member initializer list like

```
ConcurrentHashMap(int expected_size, int expected_threads_count, 
                  const Hash& hasher = Hash()) : my_hash_(hasher)
{
    //...
}
```